# mpi4py how to scatter large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to scatter a pandas dataframe to spawned children processes.

Here is what I have tried.

master.py

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import sys
import pandas as pd

comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable,
                           args=['child.py'],
                           maxprocs=5)

class Model:
    def __init__(self, num_draw):
        self.num_draw = num_draw

    def test(self):
        id = np.arange(14)
        id_repeat = np.repeat(id, self.num_draw)
        draws = np.arange(self.num_draw*14)
        data = pd.DataFrame({"id": id_repeat, "draws": draws})
        chunks = np.array_split(data,5)
        comm.scatter(chunks, root=MPI.ROOT)
        sum_gather = None
        sum_gather = comm.gather(sum_gather, root=MPI.ROOT)
        print('parent', sum_gather)

model=Model(500)
model.test()

comm.Disconnect()
```

child.py

```
from mpi4py import MPI


comm = MPI.Comm.Get_parent()
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

data = None
data = comm.scatter(data, root=0)

def li(data):
    data_sum = data.sum()
    return data_sum

data_sum=li(data)
print("child rank", rank, "after scatter", data_sum)
comm.gather(data_sum, root=0)
comm.Disconnect()
```

The program hangs without error message. If I do `model=Model(5)`, it works. So perhaps this is related to the size of dataframe? How can I scatter a large dataframe?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are coding distributed dataframes yourself rather than using the distributed dataframe functionality already available in dask (https://www.dask.org/)?

Comment: I thought dask is more for an interactive session which I don't really need. And I want to exit the cluster immediately after the script finishes running to preserve the resources allocated to me.

Comment: You can write dask scripts like any other Python scripts - they do not need to be interactive. They can also have integration with common HPC schedulers: https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/